# understand spring xml annotation metadata?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, annotations

```
<context:annotation-config/>
 <context:component-scan...
```

this is used for class that i need to annotated with @Repository @Service @Component...

```
    <context:spring-configured />
<context:component-scan...
```

use if i need to use @Configurable

```
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<context:component-scan...
```

use if i need @Transactional  , beside this what other metadata do I need to add in xml in order to use transaction management?

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

what is the need to add this in xml ? for what purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

In order to use transaction management you also need to declare a *transactionManager* to use. That declaration depends on the approach you use to access the data. For example, for plain JDBC you write:

```
<bean id = "transactionManager" class = "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name = "dataSource" ref = "dataSource" />
</bean>
```

---

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

This declaration is used to handle *@PersistenceContext* and *@PersistenceUnit* annotations for JPA data access configuration. Hovewer, support for this annotations also included in `<context:annotation-config />`, so you don't need to declare it explicitly if you use `<context:annotation-config />`.

Answer (score 2):

From [spring javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html)

> BeanPostProcessor that processes PersistenceUnit  and PersistenceContext annotations, for injection of the corresponding JPA resources EntityManagerFactory  and EntityManager. Any such annotated fields or methods in any Spring-managed object will automatically be injected.

> This post-processor will inject sub-interfaces of EntityManagerFactory and EntityManager if the annotated fields or methods are declared as such. The actual type will be verified early, with the exception of a shared ("transactional") EntityManager reference, where type mismatches might be detected as late as on the first actual invocation.